# Program working fine for relatively smaller numbers but goes haywire for very large numbers

Tags: c

I was working on a problem which asked to compute the smallest number of notes to give an amount input by the user.
**NOTE**: The only allowed denominations were 1, 2, 5, 10, 50, and 100.

**THE ISSUE**: My code works fine for smaller values like 3000, 4000, etc. but gives the wrong answer for really large numbers like 1234554875687.

Why is this so and what is the solution to that?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main (void)
{   int money, _100, r100, _50, r50, _10, r10, _5, r5, _2, r2, _1;
    
    printf("Enter the amount of money you wanna have but will never get : ");
    scanf("%d", &money);
 
    _100 = money/100;       
    r100 = money % 100;     
    _50 = r100/50;          
    r50 = r100 % 50;        
    _10 = r50/10;            
    r10 = r50 % 10;          
    _5 = r10/5;             
    r5 = r10 % 5;           
    _2 = r5/2;              
    r2 = r5 % 2;            
    _1 = r2/1;              

    printf("No of notes required of 100 are %d\n", _100);
    printf("No of notes required of 50 are %d\n", _50);
    printf("No of notes required of 10 are %d\n", _10);
    printf("No of notes required of 5 are %d\n", _5);
    printf("No of notes required of 2 are %d\n", _2);
    printf("No of notes required of 1 are %d\n", _1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: An `int` can typically only represent numbers up to 2³¹ - 1; use a wider data type. The exact choice depends on your environment.

Comment: Look up integer limit

Comment: `1234554875687` is likely too big to fit in an `int` variable (typically 32 bits); try using `long long int` or `int64_t`.

Comment: 1234554875687 is larger than a 32-bit integer can represent.  If you actually need to handle numbers of that magnitude then you need to use a data type that can represent them.  `long long` would be such a type.  Remember to adjust your `printf` and `scanf` directives to be appropriate for the type you choose.

Comment: Please choose a title which is useful for others with the same issue

Answer (score 3):

On many platforms (including yours, it seems), the `int` data type is 32 bits wide – which means it can hold a maximum value of `2147483647`. The test value you cite for failure is *much* larger than this, so your program exhibits peculiar (undefined) behaviour.

To allow for a *much* larger range of numbers, you can use the `long long int` type; or, better still (IMHO), the `int64_t` type (defined in the `<stdint.h>` header).

When using this type, you will need to change your format specifiers for `scanf` and `printf` accordingly. The `SCNd64` and `PRId64` specifiers (defined in the `<inttypes.h>` header) should be used for input and output (respectively) of 64-bit signed integers in the `d` format. These are defined as tokens that *include* delimiting double quotes (e.g. `"lld"` for `PRId64`), so the format strings look a bit weird, at first; but you'll get used to that.

Here's a version using the above:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>   // For int64_t
#include <inttypes.h> // For PRId64 and SCNd64

int main(void)
{
    int64_t money, _100, r100, _50, r50, _10, r10, _5, r5, _2, r2, _1;
    printf("Enter the amount of money you wanna have but will never get : ");
    if (scanf("%" SCNd64, &money) != 1) {
        printf("You gave invalid input, so I'll assume you don't want any money");
        money = 0;
    }

    _100 = money / 100;
    r100 = money % 100;
    _50 = r100 / 50;
    r50 = r100 % 50;
    _10 = r50 / 10;
    r10 = r50 % 10;
    _5 = r10 / 5;
    r5 = r10 % 5;
    _2 = r5 / 2;
    r2 = r5 % 2;
    _1 = r2 / 1;

    printf("No of notes required of 100 are %" PRId64 "\n", _100);
    printf("No of notes required of 50 are %" PRId64 "\n", _50);
    printf("No of notes required of 10 are %" PRId64 "\n", _10);
    printf("No of notes required of 5 are %" PRId64 "\n", _5);
    printf("No of notes required of 2 are %" PRId64 "\n", _2);
    printf("No of notes required of 1 are %" PRId64 "\n", _1);
    return 0;
}
```

Note also that I have added a check for the return value of the `scanf` call; this is something that you should get used to doing – it will save you a lot of time and grief, in the long run.

---

Since (at least) the C 2011 Standard, a `long long int` must be *at least* 64 bits in width, so it may be easier to use the `long long int` and just change your `%d` format specifiers (in both the `scanf` and `printf` calls) to `%lld` – thus removing the need for the extra two header files and the use of the `PRId64` and `SCNd64` format strings.

From [this C11 Draft Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> ##### 5.2.4.2.1 Sizes of integer types
>
> 1     The values given below shall be replaced by constant expressions suitable for use in **`#if`** preprocessing directives. … Their implementation-defined values shall be equal or greater in magnitude (absolute value) to those shown, with the same sign.
> …
>     —  maximum value for an object of
> **`type long long int`**
>          **`LLONG_MAX +9223372036854775807 // 2⁶³ − 1`**

Comment: IIRC, The C Standard now dictates that a `long long int` be *at least* 64 bits wide; this means that you can use `long long int` as an 'easier' alternative and use the `%lld` format specifier for your `scanf` and `printf` calls. I'm looking for the relevant section of the C Standard and will possibly update my answer if/when I find that...

Comment: C 2018 5.2.4.2.1 1 specifies that `LLONG_MAX` must be at least 9223372036854775807.

Comment: Good points, but this appears to be a homework assignment. Many schools with intro C or C++ courses, in my experience, have students access Linux servers where their code is compiled. Many of these servers are built for stability and not to be cutting edge, so there's a decent chance an old version of CC is being used that does not implement recent C standards.

Comment: @Eric Thanks. Fortunately, it's the same section in the C11 Draft that I generally use for citations.

Comment: @Chris - Is C11 really *recent*?

Comment: Base don some of the technical schools I've seen, they can be at least 10 years behind the curve on infrastructure.

Comment: @Chris Fair comment.

Answer (score 1):

Most C compilers usually declares 4 bytes for an `int` variable. But your number takes around 6 bytes(`0x11F71346F27`). First try to find the size of your number and data type using `sizeof()` buit-in function. Then decide which data type to use.

Hint :- Try `long`. Or `unsigned long` if you hold only positive numbers.

Note :- Remember to use the correct format specifier in your `printf()` and `scanf()` function calls (e.g.:- `%li` for `long` or `%lu` for `unsigned long`)